# How to create subsets of rows untill condition is False and keep doing this?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, subset

I have a data frame that is filled with all passes of a football match from both teams. Now I want to create subsets for every attacking sequence which is as long as the condition `Passes$Ontvanger[i] == Passes$Passer[i+1]` is met.

I tried to loop it over all the rows and create a subset at the point where the condition is False. The code succeeds to save the first passing sequence. However, I would like to keep going and make subsets for all sequences. Meaning that this sequences stopped at row 6 and I want to make a new subset starting from row 7 untill it breaks again.

```
seq <- Passes[1,]
for (i in 2:836) {
while (Passes$Ontvanger[i] == Passes$Passer[i+1]) {
seq <- rbind(seq, Passes[i,])
    i <- i + 1

 }
  return(seq)
}
```

Comment: Can you add your dataset here ?

Comment: It is a data frame in which each row consists of a time stamp, column with the passer of the ball, column with the receiver of the ball and somme additional information that is not relevant for this problem.

Comment: It seems to me that `data.table::rleid` can be of help here, but it's impossible to know without some toy data. Try editing your post and pasting the results of `dput(head(Passes))`.

Answer (score 0):

your codes follow a wrong logic. There should be only a loop and If statements. Then you will need to create a list and a counter. I rewrote the codes as follows. hope it helps.

```
seq <- list(Passes[1,]) 
## set a counter to 1 
cnt <- 1

for (i in 1:835)  # 1:length(Passes)-1
   {   
    if (Passes$Ontvanger[i] == Passes$Passer[i+1]) {
       seq[[cnt]] <- c(seq[[cnt]], Passes[i,])
       }   
    else ## increase the counter   
       {
       cnt <- cnt+1   
       } #endif
   } #end for
```

Also notice, for creating dynamic lists in R, we simply need to use "[[i]]" to extend the list. creating a empty list at the beginning of a programme is a better practice too. consider:

```
seq <- list()
```

now I would like to extend the list and add meta information:

```
seq[[1]] <- c("this is a test",2019)
seq[[2]] <- "The end"
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the code and it helps a lot. I created an empy list first and did your code like this:  seq <- list()
cnt <- 1
## set a counter to 1 cnt <- 1

for (i in 1:836) {   
  if (Passes$Ontvanger[i] == Passes$Passer[i+1]) {
    seq[[cnt]] <- c(seq[[cnt]], Passes[i,])
    i <- i + 1   }   
  else ## increase the counter   
  {
    cnt <- cnt+1   
  } #endif
} #end for
However I get an error that subscript is out of bounds in seq[[cnt]]. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @NickyBoon Sorry, I corrected the code, I should not have used the i<-i+1 within the loop. Also, you should begin the loop with 1 and finish it with N-1, I corrected this too.